# How to define lambda function within a function?

Tags: lambda, typescript

I have an issue, where I cannot create lambda function within my function. I have the following:

```
start(){
        var idleTime = 0;
        var idleInterval = this.$interval(timerIncrement, 1000);

        $(document).on('mousemove keypress', function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });

        function timerIncrement(){
                idleTime = idleTime + 1;
                if (idleTime > 2) {
                    this.$interval.cancel(idleInterval);
                    this.Service.logout();
                }
        }
}
```

I would like to function `timerIncrement` to have the same scope, so that it can cancel the interval when the `idleTime` is greater than some value. Right now, I cannot access `$interval` from within the function `timerIncrement`.  Any ideas?

So far I've tried this:

```
      function timerIncrement(){
            return ()=> {
                idleTime = idleTime + 1;
                if (idleTime > 2) {
                    this.$interval.cancel(idleInterval);
                    this.Service.logout();
                }
            }
        }
```

However, the function inside return never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, it wasn't that hard - I just had to define the function as variable.

```
        var timerIncrement:Function = () => {
            idleTime = idleTime + 1;
            if (idleTime > 2) {
                this.$interval.cancel(idleInterval);
                this.Service.logout();
            }
        };
```

And the scope is right.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, you can also make the following change:

```
var idleInterval = this.$interval(timerIncrement.bind(this), 1000);
```

I don't recommend it for your use case but sometimes it may come handy.